# C++: Removing Comments from a String?

Tags: c++, string, comments, erase

I'm doing an assignment that reads in data from a text file and I have to put the data into a vector while filtering out numbers that start with 0 and comments. I have everything down except for the filtering of comments. What I have in theory should work, but I'm just having trouble executing it. This is the problem code:

```
vector<string> nums_after;
for(int i = 0; i < nums_before.size(); i++)
{
    string current = nums_before[i];
    if (current.front() == '(')
    {
        current.erase(current.find("(*"), current.find("*)"));
    }
    if (current.front() == '0')
    {
        continue;
    }
    nums_after.push_back(current);
}
```

My sample file looks like this:

```
101481
10974
1013
(* comment *)0
28292
35040
35372
0000
7155
7284
96110
26175
```

But my code only filters out the (* and not even the whitespace after the asterisk. I think I'm just having trouble combining the erase() and find() functions. Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: Realized my problem was that the comment line was being broken down into three separate lines: (*, comment, and *)0. I'm now suspecting a problem with my getline function. This is what it looks like:

```
int main() {
string line;
string fileName;
cout << "Enter the name of the file to be read: ";
cin >> fileName;

ifstream inFile{fileName};

istream_iterator<string> infile_begin {inFile};
istream_iterator<string> eof{};
vector<string> nums_before {infile_begin, eof};
while (getline(inFile, line))
{
    nums_before.push_back(line);
}
```

This comes right before the first block of code.

Comment: How are you supposed to handle something with nested comments? `10 03 (* 05 11 (* 10 03 *) 10 01 *) 03 100` requires different methods of parsing depending on what your instructions say. EDIT: Are you also only parsing integers?

Comment: I'm supposed to get rid of anything that's in-between comments, but the text files my program is supposed to be able to handle don't have nested comments

Comment: Check my answer. You need to know, that erase takes beginning position and AMOUNT of characters to erase, not ending position - NOT `(begin, end)`, but `(begin, end - begin)` - that will remove all characters between `begin` and `end`, but it will not touch found ending characters, so you need to add their count, 2 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

what is in nums_before? i'm guessing that the full text splitted by spaces?
in that case it makes sense that it removes only the (*, because that is what that is in the current string you are looking at is "(*". the next string is "comment" and the next one is "*)0".

Comment: Yeah sorry, nums_before is the raw data extracted from the file and nums_after is supposed to be just the integers after filtering out the leading-zero numbers and comments. The way the text is written I didn't do it in code so all the integers including the (* comment *)0 is supposed to be one line

Answer (score 0):

in such situations, you should opt for a `stack` data structure or reverse iteration.

```
void func ( int &error, int inc, int &i ) {
    error += inc;
    i -= 2;
}

string output;
for ( int i=nums_before.size()-1; i>=0; ++i ) {
    if ( nums_before[i] == ')' && nums_before[i-1] == '*' ) {
        static int error;
        func ( error, 1, i );

        while ( error != 0 ) {
            if ( nums_before[i] == ')' && nums_before[i-1] == '*' ) 
                func ( error, 1, i );
            else if ( nums_before[i] == '*' && nums_before[i-1] == '(' ) 
                func ( error, -1, i );
            else --i;
        }
    } else output += nums_before[i];
}

cout << output.reverse() << endl;
```

input: `101481 10974 1013 (* comment *)0 28292 35040 35372 0000 7155 7284 96110 26175`

output: `101481 10974 1013 0 28292 35040 35372 0000 7155 7284 96110 26175`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, but nested comments not supported:

```
std::string removeComments(std::string str)
{
    std::string::size_type begin, end;
    while((begin = str.find("(*")) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if(((end = str.find("*)")) != std::string::npos) && (end > begin))
            str.erase(begin, end - begin + 2);
        else
            break;
    }
    return str;
}
```

---

Test:

```
std::string test = "1745 2355 (* comment *) 0 1454 4352 4234 (* comment *)";
std::cout << removeComments(test) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
1745 2355  0 1454 4352 4234
```

---

Example without using functions:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
for(int i=0; i<strings.size(); ++i)
{
    std::string::size_type begin, end;
    while((begin = strings[i].find("(*")) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if(((end = strings[i].find("*)")) != std::string::npos) && (end > begin))
            strings[i].erase(begin, end - begin + 2);
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to incorporate your idea into my code but didn't get the same output. My syntax may be wrong because I didn't use it as a function, as we're supposed to do it as straight code without functions yet. I replaced line 7 of my code with lines 3-10 of your code.

Comment: @AlyssaJune Edited - added not very much modified version without using function.

Comment: It wasn't working, then I altered my print function to separate the data with new lines as opposed to spaces and saw that (* was one line, comment was another, and *)0 was a third line. Now I'm suspecting a problem with my getline function. I'll update my question to display the code.